# Old thermostat to Hive thermostat

Tags: hvac, thermostat

My wife decided we needed a smart thermostat... which means I need to install said thermostat...

Currently a Bryant Evolution series is mounted. She purchased the Hive with Hub when it was on sale.

The Bryant is wired using A, B, C, and D at the thermostat. Those wires run to my Bryant Plus80v furnace. They plug into the corresponding spots on the 4 circuit communication connector. There are also at least 3 wires that are not connected on either end.

My question is this... Can I disconnect the wires from both ends and move them over to the bigger board (W2, Y1, DHUM, G, COM 24V, W/W1, Y/Y2, R)? Obviously using only the necessary ones that correspond with the Hive.[image][image][image]

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your furnace please?

Comment: *"My wife decided ..."*, *"She purchased ..."*  You can relax, I think she has it covered.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I have added the wiring diagram.

Comment: A picture of your '4 circut communication connector' would also be helpful.

Comment: Do you need the dehumidification functionality of your system?

Comment: I added the 4 circuit connector which is PL7 on the diagram. I also added the main board (even though I'm sure you knew what it was).

Comment: No I dont need the dehumidification function.

Answer (score 1):

### You can do this, but you'll lose some fancy features

The rewiring you describe (from using the ABCD commlink to using the standard 24VAC inputs) should be supported by your control board.  However, there are downsides to this, namely that your system will act as a good two-stage forced-air system, without full command modulating functionality or the ability to display feedback (such as fault codes) on the thermostat.  So, go ahead, as long as you are cool trading these communicating functions for the Hive's "smarts".

Comment: Is there another method you would suggest? Mainly what we (she) are aiming for is the ability to change the temp from our phones and program it to a lower temp when we arent home and heat when we are going to be home.